# SharePoint 2010 - One email to combine changes for multiple lists

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, alert, document-library

I need one email sent out when anything changes to multiple lists on my site. To make it even more complicated this email needs to go out weekly and include all changes in that past week.

Users currently have alerts set up, but they are complaining that they are receiving too many emails. I need a way to combine these into one email.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Ninel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, TimerJob is your friend:

Create a storage list, in that list keep changes from the other lists you want ( on itemupdated or itemcreated ). Then run you job weekly and send email with cumulative updates.

-p

Comment: I'm a little new to all of this...if you could elaborate a little more. How can I get changes from other lists into the "storage" list?

Comment: How can I set up a weekly timer job?